# A doubt regarding attenuation and intensity of electromagnetic waves in different mediums

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Consider a source of EM radiation in space.Since there is only vacuum there is no attenuation but as we move farther and farther away from the source its intensity decrease by 1/r^2 according to inverse square law.Now say there is a source of EM wave on earth like a radio tower.Here the intensity decreases with distance but there is also attenuation of the wave due to energy loss as it travels through different mediums, am I right?Is my concept right or is there another correct explanation?

Also does an EM wave in space due to vacuum have the capability to travel infinitely whereas an EM wave travelling in any medium like air ,water etc have only a finite range because of energy loss and drop in amplitude?

Just ignore things like red shifting and Doppler effect.

Answer (score 0):

The attenuation an EM wave suffers in air depends very strongly on the atmospheric conditions and on the frequency. There is an enormous difference between absorption at 100MHz vs. 4GHz vs 25GHz and/or meteorological phenomena such as rain, snow, ice, clouds, etc. As a general comment one can safely say that up to even 1GHz atmospheric attenuation in dry air is essentially irrelevant in practice. Above 1GHz there is a general trend of increasing absorption rate with frequency with a few sudden resonant absorption bands scattered around, very famously at ~24GHz and ~60GHz where much recent short-range radio research activity aimed at low probability of intercept comms has been expended.

The atmosphere also scatters at RF, not because of particulates that can scatter off visible light, but mainly caused by the variation of the dielectric permittivity of air that itself is caused by gravitational density stratification. Of course, you need enormous distances to observe but transmission at HF and below is intended for very long ranges.

Comment: ok so does an EM wave in space due to vacuum have the capability to travel infinitely whereas an EM wave travelling in any medium like air ,water etc have only a finite range?